# DeNormalize Many to Many but don’t want to store redundant data in SQL world

Tags: sql, database-design, denormalization, redundancy

Say I have `newsletters` and then `subscribers`:

Whenever a user `subscribes` to a newsletter we need to store this in a table - the subscribers list.

Should I store this in the `newsletter table` or in the `user table`? I.e. should the newsletter store the list of subscribers or should the user store the list of newsletters he has subscribed too? Both the cases will be widely used. User will need to show the newsletters he has subscribed too and newsletters will need to show the users subscribed to it.

How can I design a table structure for optimized for reads? I **don’t** want to go the NoSql route.

Comment: Why/How have you determined you need to store this in a redundant manner at all? If the `many-to-many` table is appropriately indexed retrieval should be quite straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what many-to-many tables are for.  You store the relationship between the two in a separate table.  Example:

```
newsletter
 id,
 name,
 etc.

subscriber
  id,
  last, 
  first,
  etc.

newsletter_subscriber
  id,
  subscriber_id,
  newsletter_id,
  other attributes, etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

Are your `Users` and `Subscribers` tables the same? If not they should be. The `Users` table should contain your users, the `Newsletters` table, your newsletters and your `Subscribers` the relation between the two.

Say you have:

Users

```
user_id    name
1          a
2          b
3          c
```

Newsletters

```
newsletter_id   name
1               x
2               y
3               z
```

Subscribers

```
user_id   newsletter_id
1         1
1         2
2         2
```

User a is subscribed to x and y, user b is subscribed to y. You should also add indexing after `user_id` and `newsletter_id` to the Subscribers table and the PK should be `(user_id,newsletter_id)`.